# MariaDB/MySQL: Calculations on table with self join giving double results

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to get data from a single database table using join. This data is also being calculated (added) to prevent loading extra rows in the result set.
The data is from two different wallboard_id's. The issue is when there is a user which is in only 1 of the 2 wallboard_id's, the end result is being calculated twice.

I have tried all kind of different ways, with right and left join and union, but nothing gives a different result.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78853/6/0) I have currently with the double results. User5 should return 358686 for totalcall and 1 for numcalls, however as you can see it is added twice (most likely because of the join).

Is there another way to achieve this? Or a quick fix I have overlooked?

**Edit:**
Found a solution that works. Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78853/17/0) for it.
It might not be the best and most elegant solution, but it does the job.

If anybody has a way to simplify this, I'm open for suggestions.

**Edit2:**
So the problem I was facing is that a user can be logged in on only the second wallboard (wallboard_id = 2608143), instead of the normal use-case where the user is logged in on both (wallboard_id = 2591849 & wallboard_id = 2608143).
The values returned need to be combined into 1 row, so the handling doesn't have to be done in the application (use SQL if possible). Where the first wallboard (2591849) takes precedence over the second (2608143).

My original question combined all the values correctly, however it did it twice for the user(s) with only logged on the second wallboard (2608143).

Comment: I think you could simplify the problem

Comment: Not sure what you mean with simplifying the problem @Strawberry.

Comment: You say that the first wallboard takes precedence, but you are doing the average on results from both wallboards. Can you clarify this? Best would that you explain what you want in each columns if possible. It is possible to retro engineer your query, but it would be simpler if you write what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now this seems to solve the problem: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78853/17/0). It is far from elegant, but it seems to do what I want.

**Edit:**
This is what I finally came up with (no SQL Fiddle update seeing as it's down at this moment).

```sql
SELECT IFNULL(join3.id,t1.id) AS id, t1.name, t1.connected, 
IFNULL((join3.activecalls * 10 + t1.activecalls * 20),t1.activecalls * 20) AS activecalls, 
IFNULL(join3.api_time,t1.api_time) AS api_time, 
IFNULL(((t1.totalcallduration + join3.totalcallduration) / 1000),(t1.totalcallduration / 1000)) AS totalcallduration, 
IFNULL((t1.numcalls + join3.numcalls),t1.numcalls) AS numcalls, 
IFNULL( IFNULL(((t1.totalcallduration + join3.totalcallduration) / (t1.numcalls + join3.numcalls) / 1000), (t1.totalcallduration / t1.numcalls / 1000)),0)  AS averagecalltime, 
IFNULL(join3.wallboard_id,t1.wallboard_id) as wallboard_id 
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN ( 
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id1, u.name AS name1, MAX(api_time) AS api_time_max1 FROM Table1 u WHERE u.wallboard_id = 2608143 AND u.api_time >= ( 
        SELECT DATE_SUB(MAX(api_time), INTERVAL 12 HOUR) FROM Table1 WHERE wallboard_id = 2608143 ) GROUP BY u.name 
    ) join1 ON t1.id = join1.id1 
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT * FROM Table1 t2 JOIN ( 
        SELECT MAX(id) AS id2, u.name AS name2, MAX(api_time) AS api_time_max2 FROM Table1 u WHERE u.wallboard_id = 2591849 AND u.api_time >= ( 
            SELECT DATE_SUB(MAX(api_time), INTERVAL 12 HOUR) FROM Table1 WHERE wallboard_id = 2591849 ) GROUP BY u.name 
        ) join2 ON t2.id = join2.id2 
    ) join3 ON t1.name = join3.name
```

Comment: If a User does not have any row where wallboard_id = 2608143 and api_time bounded (max api time on that wallboard and 12 hours before that) your first join will remove the line. So I am not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: The database will always have a api_time filled in, so this value will not be empty. A user not having wallboard_id = 2608143 should not be the case as well, I will try to clarify this in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

There are things that I do not understand from you question, so I made a few assumptions about what you want in each column :

- id : id of the last row by user name (here last row means 'where id = max(id) and wallboard_id IN (2608143, 2591849)')
- name : user name
- connected : 1 if connected on the last row from either wallboard ?
- activecalls : ? I did a sum, but it seems you want 10 or 20, and it is not clear
- api_time : max api time for user
- totalcallduration : (totalcallduration on wallboard 2608143 + totalcallduration on wallboard 2591849)
- numcalls : (numcalls on wallboard 2608143 + numcalls on wallboard 2591849)
- averagecalltime :  totalcallduration / numcalls
- wallboard_id : ??

So I ended up with this query, I hope the inlined comments will make what is done inside the query clear :

```
SELECT MAX(max_id) as id, 
name,
MAX(connected) as connected, 
SUM(activecalls) activecalls, -- I don t understand what you want 
MAX(max_api_time) as max_api_time, 
SUM(totalcallduration) as totalcallduration, 
SUM(numcalls) as numcalls,
COALESCE(SUM(totalcallduration) / SUM(numcalls), 0) as averagecalltime
-- wallboard_id -- I don t understand what you want

FROM (
    -- Info from last row in wallboard 2608143
    SELECT t_wall.name as name, max_id, connected, activecalls, max_api_time, totalcallduration / 1000 as totalcallduration, numcalls
    FROM Table1 t_wall
    Join (
        -- Max id and api time by name on wall board 2608143, time bounded
        SELECT name, MAX(id) as max_id, MAX(api_time) as max_api_time
        FROM Table1 u 
            -- wallboard 2608143 
        WHERE u.wallboard_id = 2608143 
            -- and last 12 hours
            AND u.api_time >= (SELECT DATE_SUB(MAX(api_time), INTERVAL 12 HOUR) FROM Table1 WHERE wallboard_id = 2608143) 
        GROUP BY u.name
    ) last_row_data_1 ON t_wall.name = last_row_data_1.name AND last_row_data_1.max_id = t_wall.id
  
    UNION ALL -- union : there might be 1 or 2 rows by user name (or 0), one for each wallboard
    
    -- Info from last row in wallboard 2591849
    SELECT t_wall.name, max_id, connected, activecalls, max_api_time, totalcallduration / 1000 as totalcallduration, numcalls
    FROM Table1 t_wall
    Join (
        -- Max id and api time by name on wall board 2591849, time bounded
        SELECT name, MAX(id) as max_id, MAX(api_time) as max_api_time
        FROM Table1 u 
            -- wallboard 2591849 
        WHERE u.wallboard_id = 2591849 
            -- and last 12 hours
            AND u.api_time >= (SELECT DATE_SUB(MAX(api_time), INTERVAL 12 HOUR) FROM Table1 WHERE wallboard_id = 2591849) 
        GROUP BY u.name
    ) last_row_data_1 ON t_wall.name = last_row_data_1.name AND last_row_data_1.max_id = t_wall.id
) as both_wallboard_data
GROUP BY name
```

[SQL Fiddle with given data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78853/34/0)

Comment: I really appreciate the time spent to give this answer. I will have to look into it more closely to see if it is helpful. I agree with the lack of information and therefor the need to make assumptions. However I already see some things I could use to improve (like the sum()).
I will not accept a answer until I have time to figure it out, I do like your suggestion even though it isn't resulting in what I wanted (again lack of details on my part).